# jQuery mousedown not updating

Tags: jquery, mousedown

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zklimczak/14kz8c7n/6/) that I've been messing with:

```js
$('.container').mousedown(function(e) {
    $('.coords').text(e.pageX + ' : ' + e.pageY);
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
</div>
<div>Coords: <p class='coords'> </p> </div>
```

I'm trying to program it such that when you click inside the box and move the mouse around the coordinates will also change - then if you leave the box, it's not updated.  Right now, the coordinates will only change when you let go of the mouse button and then click again.  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create more that a mousedown function. You need to use mousemove as well. Here are the docs on that, https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

You could do something like this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2rv167L/)).

```
var mouse_clicked;

$('.container').mousedown(function(e) {
    mouse_clicked = true;
});

$('.container').mouseup(function(e) {
    mouse_clicked = false;
});

$('.container').mouseleave(function(e) {
    mouse_clicked = false;
});

$('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
  if (mouse_clicked) {
    $('.coords').text(e.pageX + ' : ' + e.pageY);
  }
});
```

Here is a different way of doing it that looks a little cleaner

```
var mouse_clicked;
$('.container').on({
  'mousedown': function() {
    mouse_clicked = true;
  },
  'mouseup': function() {
    mouse_clicked = false;
  },
  'mouseleave': function() {
    mouse_clicked = false;
  },
  'mousemove': function(e) {
    if (mouse_clicked) {
      $('.coords').text(e.pageX + ' : ' + e.pageY);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @zklim - No prob, I also added a mouseleave because I noticed that the var stays true if you leave the div while mousedown. I added a cleaner way to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach is to use a switch that detects when the mouse is held down. This example works on document but could easily be adapted for an element:

```
var isDown = false;
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
   isDown = true;
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(isDown) {
        console.log(e.pageX + ',' + e.pageY);
    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
   isDown = false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kynwywss/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would track it like this.

```js
var mousePosition = { x: 0, y: 0};
var BUTTONS = { LEFT: 0, MIDDLE: 1, RIGHT: 2};
var mouseDown = [];
var mouseDownCount = 0;

var buttonInfo = document.getElementById("buttons");
var posInfo = document.getElementById("pos");

// Track mouse all the time.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function storeMouse(event) {
    mousePosition = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
    };
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    mouseDown[event.button] = true;
    ++mouseDownCount;
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    mouseDown[event.button] = false;
    --mouseDownCount;
});

function checkMouseStuff() {
    var buttons = [];

    if (mouseDownCount) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mouseDown.length; ++i) {
            if (mouseDown[i]) {
                buttons.push("Button: " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    buttonInfo.textContent = buttons.join(", ");
    posInfo.textContent = mousePosition.x + " : " + mousePosition.y;
}

window.setInterval(checkMouseStuff, 10);
```

```html
<p id="pos"></p>
<p id="buttons"></p>
```